# Trait value not usable in template expression

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-meta-programming, traits

I've already posted a question like this but it didn't provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. So here it is:

```
//static_const_with_template_specialization_test.h
#include <iostream>
enum class EnumFoo {A=10, B=20, C=30};
enum class EnumTest {D=40, E=50, F=60};

class MyStruct {};

template <EnumFoo enumFoo>
struct MyStructTraits
  {
  static const EnumTest MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE;
  };

template <>
struct MyStructTraits<EnumFoo::A>
  {
  static const EnumTest MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE;
  };


template<EnumTest genericEnumTest>
void fooTest()
  {
  std::cout << "generic fooTest\n";
  }

template<>
void fooTest<EnumTest::D>();

void anotherFunction(EnumTest test);


//static_const_with_template_specialization_test.cpp
#include "static_const_with_template_specialization_test.h"

template<>
void fooTest<EnumTest::D>()
  {
  std::cout << "EnumTest::D fooTest\n";
  }

template <EnumFoo type>
  const EnumTest MyStructTraits<type>::MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE = EnumTest::F;


template <>
  const EnumTest MyStructTraits<EnumFoo::A>::MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE = EnumTest::D;

void anotherFunction(EnumTest test)
  {
  std::cout << "anotherFunction\n";
  }

// main.cpp
int main()
  {
  fooTest<EnumTest::D>(); // ok
  fooTest<EnumTest::E>(); // ok
  anotherFunction(MyStructTraits<EnumFoo::A>::MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE); // ok
  fooTest<MyStructTraits<EnumFoo::A>::MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE>(); // Error here
  return 1
  }
```

Problem is that it doesn't compile:

```
main.cpp:31: error: no matching function for call to 'fooTest()'
   fooTest<MyStructTraits<EnumFoo::A>::MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE>();

main.cpp:31: error: the value of 'MyStructTraits<(EnumFoo)10>::MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE' is not usable in a constant expression
   fooTest<MyStructTraits<EnumFoo::A>::MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE>();
```

Do you know why can't I use that value as a constant expression if it is constant?

Writing everything in the header doesn't help, I get multiple definition errors.

[Edit] compiled with 4.8.1

[Edit2] I guess I've solved my problem:

```
template <EnumFoo enumFoo>
struct MyStructTraits
  {
  //static const EnumTest MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE;
  static constexpr EnumTest MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE = EnumTest::F;
  };

template <>
struct MyStructTraits<EnumFoo::A>
  {
//  static const EnumTest MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE;
  static  constexpr EnumTest MY_STATIC_CONST_VALUE = EnumTest::D;
  };
```

Now I need to understand well why it doens't work without the constexpr.
I still have some "undefined reference" problems in my real code.. trying to evaluate if they depend on this constexpr fix

[EDIT 3] 
Just to share:

-constexpr indicates a value that’s not only constant, it’s known during compilation.

-const indicates a value that’s only constant, it’s not compulsory to known during compilation

that's the reason I need

Comment: Nope, it [seems to run fine](https://ideone.com/1FgzG2) after a few very minor changes.

Comment: which changes? the ones I've made with constexpr?

Comment: You left an `#include` in the code, and your `return 1` was missing a semicolon and should have returned 0.

Comment: yes, sorry for the include miss. Are you on Windows by any chance?

Comment: No, the link is to an online compiler using (I think) gcc.

Comment: that's pretty weird then

Comment: Not really. It just means your question isn't specified well enough. You should add a tag of the specific compiler you're using, and clearly mark in the question that the problem is not universal.